# Embedding jetty server for EXT GWT in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, gxt

I am trying to create an EXT GWT project with an embedded Jetty server. I am completely new to Jetty and EXT GWT. Can anyone please point me in the right direction to get started about embedding jetty server for EXT GWT project? I have read a couple of blogs and tutorials but cannot figure it out. I have also downloaded Eclipse plugin for Jetty but the project requirement states that I have to have an embedded jetty server. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you referred to [Jetty GWT](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/GWT)? There is an explicit mention of a jetty-gwt.jar that will need to be on your class path. Similarly is true for the EXT GWT jar(s).